# Unattended Upgrades - could not be installed automatically

Tags: nvidia, unattended-upgrades

I have a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and don't remember specifically installing unattended-upgrades, but it seems enabled. As part of the MOTD when logging in I see:

```
16 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details, see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```

cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log reveals these are nvidia-driver packages.

```
2021-06-06 16:49:02,358 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
2021-06-06 16:49:02,382 DEBUG fetch.run() result: 0
2021-06-06 16:49:02,391 DEBUG Packages blacklist due to conffile prompts: []
2021-06-06 16:49:02,391 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2021-06-06 16:49:02,443 DEBUG Package libnvidia-cfg1-465 has a higher version available, checking if it is from an allowed origin and is not pinned down.
2021-06-06 16:49:02,445 INFO Package libnvidia-cfg1-465 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2021-06-06 16:49:02,445 DEBUG Package libnvidia-common-465 has a higher version available, checking if it is from an allowed origin and is not pinned down.
2021-06-06 16:49:02,447 INFO Package libnvidia-common-465 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
...
2021-06-06 16:49:02,489 DEBUG Package nvidia-driver-465 has a higher version available, checking if it is from an allowed origin and is not pinned down.
2021-06-06 16:49:02,490 INFO Package nvidia-driver-465 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
```

However, I'm not able to update any of these packages and it seems as if they're all the latest version.

```
$ sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-465
nvidia-driver-465 is already installed at the requested version (465.19.01-0ubuntu1)
nvidia-driver-465 is already installed at the requested version (465.19.01-0ubuntu1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

$ sudo aptitude full-upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I'd like to keep unattended-upgrades, but seeing this message is driving me nuts. How can I get unattended-upgrades to recognize that everything is up to date, or how can I update packages that already appear to be up to date?

Comment: The question does not make clear that Unattended Upgrades messages are merely a symptom, not the actual problem. You had a source pinned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the pin in /etc/apt/preferences.d

```
ls /etc/apt/preferences.d
cuda-repository-pin-600
```

Which seemed to be leftover from a cuda install I didn't really need. So I purged the cuda install, and removed the pin.

```
sudo apt purge cuda*
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

And then was able to update the (still installed) drivers using unattended-upgrade

```
sudo unattended-upgrade -d
```

after installing the driver updates and rebooting, nvidia-smi still works

Comment: I experience the same symptom so I followed the answer. But for my case, nvidia-smi and all other cuda-related programs are really deleted. Maybe some environmental settings were different.